# How to use vlookup?

Tags: excel-formula, vlookup

How to use `Vlookup` if the data that we want to match (col_index_num) contains a formula?
I want to match the vendor name to get the addresses. But the addresses contain Proper formula because I changed the address from all `UPPERCASE` to Proper. I thought that might be the problem why I get `#N/A` result.

Comment: It's hard to tell exactly what you're struggling with, but as `#n/a` probably means the value was not found in the table, check that the value you're looking for _does_ actually exist. Start with the simplest portion of your formula, check it is working, and build it up. Posting your formula and some sample data would help. Excel _ignores case_ when doing lookup functions, so the use of `uppercase` or `proper` is unlikely to be your problem. If you want to match case sensitively, use an additional `if` and the `exact` function à la [this suggestion](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/214264).

Answer (score 0):

For vlookup , make sure the field that you are trying to look up and the source table in which you are looking up the field are in same format (Vendor name. vlooking up numbers with text format creates error most of the time)

Also, there might be possibility hat there is really no match of the values that you are looking up . (may contain space)